# X axis labels are not displaying in the figure python

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot some time series data in python. When they are visualized this is how my figure was displayed.

[image]

In the above figure the 'x axis' values are not displaying. I need them to show in the figure.

```
data = pd.read_csv("Temporary_Dataset/data.csv") 
data.set_index(data.ds, inplace=True)

# scatter the sepal_length against the sepal_width
data.plot(x='ds',y='y',figsize=(15, 6))
```

This is how the dataframe looks like

[image]

I need to show 'ds' column values for the x axis. Please someone kindly help